# MNIST fashion dataset not loading

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm doing an ML/Tensorflow hello world by working with the MNIST dataset to predict what kind of clothing something is, but when I try to load the data into my doe using data.load_data() it gives me this error:

Using TensorFlow backend.

```
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1392, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 853, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*NAME*/MNISTifying Clothing Predictor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 264, in get_file
    urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*NAME*/Python Projects/MNISTifying Clothing Predictor/MNISTifying Clothing Predictor.py", line 10, in <module>
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()
  File "/Users/*NAME*/MNISTifying Clothing Predictor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist.py", line 52, in load_data
    paths.append(get_file(fname, origin=base + fname, cache_subdir=dirname))
  File "/Users/*NAME*/MNISTifying Clothing Predictor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 268, in get_file
    raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
```

This is my code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()

print(train_labels[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Python folder and find a script called `Install Certificates.command`. Double click to run it and it will install a lib called `certifi`. This tool will handle SSL certification for you.

If you are on Mac it is here: `/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command`

Answer (score 1):

The code provided below  by you is working fine ,

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras 
from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()

print(train_labels)
```

but when you are downloading the data from particular websites been restricted by that browser.kindly refer this link to fix SSLCertVerificationError.
[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xp5G8x3SNhE)